# How could I extend <hr> from right to left?

Tags: html

Have created a div and another div stays adjacent to it but I put an hr to right aligned div but want it to expand from right to left.

Comment: Show us your code please!

Comment: Make a fiddle,Also some better problem description will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are simply using `<hr>`,  clear your space for a line then it will automatically cover the whole region. Keep your both division inside a division and put `<hr>` in you main division. It would be better if you show your code.

Comment: correct. horizontal rule by default will occupy full width.

Answer (score 0):

It will span the whole way through if you put it in the top level `div`.
You can also add CSS to it to make it stretch nicely, but that's another story.

Comment: Not necessarily `div`, any block level element will do the job.

Comment: yeah, true :) but I guess he's using 'div' (at least I hope he is)